# Foreach Json Object in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, object

I'm using Json library created by Daniel Crenna.

I have a string json document:

```
{
    "id": "00132",
    "items":[
        {
           "name":"papers"
        },
        {
           "name":"glasses"
        }
    ]
}
```

I deserialize it,  and if i want to access "id" , i can do:

```
Console.WriteLine(myjsonvar.id);
```

But if i try to foreach "items" property:

```
foreach(var item in myjsonvar.items){
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```

It displays: **"System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2[System.String, System.Object]"**

If i do another foreach inside this one:

```
 foreach(var item in myjsonvar.items){
        foreach(var properties in item){
            Console.WriteLine(properties);
        }
  }
```

I'm getting "**[name, papers]**"

How can i do to access properties like:

```
 foreach(var item in myjsonvar.items){
        var itemName = item.name;
  }
```

Thank you for your responses.

Comment: Honestly, if this is coming from MVC or WebApi you should be able to automatically resolve this if you build a class and have the model binder deserialize,  chances are you don't need to use a shotty library when most of these tools are built in

Answer (score 2):

Since `items` is an array of dictionaries, your `item` variable is a dictionary and you can try accessing objects in it using the indexer `[]`:

```
var itemName = item["name"];  // returns "papers", "glasses", etc.
```

What you pass in to the indexer is the key (property name) and what is returned is the value.

Note that the property in your JSON object can be a string, integer, boolean, another object, or an array, which is why the value of the dictionary is `System.Object`. It's up to you to cast it to its underlying type. In this case, `item["name"].ToString()` should work.

Read more here: [Dictionary Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: I think `items` is an array of dictionaries, not a dictionary itself.

Comment: @adv12 you are correct, items in an array, item is a dictionary :) but the answer should still work.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is *deserialize* your `json` string. In C#, **any** object has the `ToString()` method, which basically returns the type of the object as a string. This means that what you see: `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2[System.String, System.Object]`, is the result of an object of type `Dictionary<string, object>`'s execution of its `ToString()` method.

The reason why that library is converting that part of the json string to a dictionary, is because you do not provide it with a type it should convert to (or maybe it converts any object to a dictionary, I don't know which library you're using).

If you can specify the type the library should convert your json to, you should create a class like:

```
public class DeserializedResult {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<string> Items { get; set; }
    //you can also choose to use a dictionary if you want to keep the key "names"
    //public List<Dictionary<string, string>> Items { get; set; }
}
```

The library will probably compare the property names with the keys of the json string, and deserialize the data accordingly.

If your json string would have another key next to name, let's say 'age', then you should probably create a class that represents the data inside the items:

```
public class Person {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your `DeserializedResult`, `Items` would be:

`public List<Person> Items { get; set;}`

Answer (score 0):

Please apply my solution .

Create class for you json .

```
public class JsonCLass
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public Item[] items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

And then use follwing code for desirealize json string .

```
string strXmlData = File.ReadAllText("file.txt");//json string

            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            JsonCLass Data = serializer.Deserialize<JsonCLass>(strXmlData);

            string Id = Data.id;//Id field

            foreach (Item objitem in Data.items)
            {
                string ab = objitem.name;//Get all item of jsonID .
            }
```

Thanks .